# How can I remove an ADFS Relying Party Trust Encryption Certificate via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, adfs2.0

I can add an encryption certificate to an ADFS Relying Party Trust with the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "My RP" -EncryptionCertificate $myCert
```

I can change the certificate using that same command with a different variable for the `EncryptionCertificate` parameter, but how can I remove the certificate? Not passing a variable, passing `null` or the empty string `''` results in an exception:

```
Missing an argument for parameter 'EncryptionCertificate'. 
Specify a parameter of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2' 
and try again.
```

How can I "clear" the certificate that is in place?

Comment: [Remove-ADFSCertificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee892358.aspx) or [Remove-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee892344.aspx)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks, but neither does what I'm looking for. Remove-ADFSCertificate is used to completely remove a certificate from ADFS, and if I'm reading it right, is only valid for Token-Signing, Token-Decrypting, and Service-Communications certificates. (But I'll run it with the -WhatIf param and see what I get.) I need to keep the certificate in place on another RP. Remove-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust will remove the RP. I could then re-add it without the certificate, but I'd prefer not to entirely drop and recreate it if possible.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I confirmed that, in spite of the TechNet article says, Remove-ADFSCertificate does not apply to Token-Encrypting certificates for Relying Parties. Instead, it applies to Token-Decrypting certificates for federated partners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it. In order to remove the encryption certificate from an existing relying party, you have to use the $null variable:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "My RP" -EncryptionCertificate $null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that PowerShell statement doesn't remove it from the Encryption tab in the ADFS GUI. So while it may have the desired effect, it's not clear from the GUI whether or not it's actually being used or not.

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "My RP" -EncryptionCertificate $null
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, but I was trying to figure out how to empty the list of RequestSigningCertificates (which is different that the original question - for which the original answer still stands) for an ADFS RP, and it took me a few minutes to figure out (during which I stumble across this thread) that Set-ADFSRelyingParty accepts an array of X509Certificate2 objects now, so you can't do:

Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "My RP" -RequestSigningCertificate $null

instead, you need to pass it an empty array:

Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "My RP" -EncryptionCertificate @()

worked for me.

Hopefully that's helpful to someone, somewhere, someday.

(doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsrelyingpartytrust?view=windowsserver2022-ps)